# Add To A List Of Thread Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a list of tasks that will call a function with a parameter that is an object.

This object is a list of 100 other objects. I then send this list of tasks to `Parallel.ForEach` to process the tasks.

What I am finding out is the parameter is changing for all objects, which doesn't make sense to me.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var listOfTestTasks = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();
    List<string> stest = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        stest.Add("Test " + i);
        listOfTestTasks.Add(new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => TestFunc(stest)));
    }

}

static private void TestFunc(List<string> test)
{
    int i = test.Count();
}
```

You would think that the first item in the `listOfTestTasks` would contain a call to `TestFunc` with `sTest` containing one entry of `"Test 0"`.

That isn't the case, all items in `listOfTestTasks` have `"TestFunc"` with a parameter containing `sTest` with a list of 5 string values of `"Test 0"` through `"Test 4"`.

This doesn't make any sense to me and I am doing something really wrong here.

Comment: http://www.wolfpack.pe.kr/123 this will help you. you need to think about lock when more than one thread access same variables. even this site written by Korean, I think it'll be gives you a concept how's your code will be.

Comment: Each task is accessing the same list instance after all tasks were created and so they must return the same result

Comment: In short, by the time you start your tasks(and they run), `stest` is already populated with the 5 values

Comment: What is it your want to achieve? or do you just want clarification why

Comment: My objective is to call a function with values that are different. On my real program I am trying to send a List<object> into the function and this List<object> holds a different number of objects and of course, each object loaded with different information. What is happening is there could be 500 tasks, but they are all passing sTest from the last iteration.